# Showing that $\mathcal{T}_{d_1}\subset \mathcal{T}_{d_2}$ if $d_1(x, y)\leq d_2(x, y), \forall x, y \in X$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces, alternative-proof

I'm looking for feedback to the following proof. I'm most interested in knowing whether there is a more straightforward proof.

Let $d_1, d_2$ be two metrics on $X$ s.t. $\forall x, y\in X: d_1(x, y)\leq d_2(x, y)$. We will show that $\mathcal{T}_{d_1}\subset \mathcal{T}_{d_2}$, where the two topologies are topologies generated by the metrics $d_1, d_2$ on $X$. Thus let $U \in \mathcal{T}_{d_1}$ and $x \in U$. Then for some $r_1 > 0$ the ball $B_{d_1}(x, r_1)\subset U$. Suppose that $y \in B_{d_1}(x, r_1)$ and let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then for $r_2 := \max\{r_1, d_2(x, y) + \epsilon\}$ we have that $y \in B_{d_2}(x, r_2)$. Then if $B_{d_2}(x, r_2) \not\subset U$, it follows that for some $z \in X\setminus U$ we have that $d_2(x, z) < r_2$. But $r_1 < d_1(x, z) \leq d_2(x, z)$ by $B_{d_1}(x, r_1)\subset U$. Therefore, $d_2(x, z) < r_2 = \max\{r_1, d_2(x, y)\}$ violates the triangle inequality $d_2(x, z) \leq d_2(x, y) + d_2(y, z)$ as $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary. Thus $B_{d_2}(x, r_2) \subset U$ so that by definition $U \in \mathcal{T}_{d_2}$. Hence $\mathcal{T}_{d_1}\subset \mathcal{T}_{d_2}$.

Answer (score 3):

It's much simpler:

Let $O$ be $d_1$-open. Let $x \in O$ be arbitrary.

Then there is some $r>0$ so that $B_{d_1}(x,r) \subseteq O$.
By the inequality:

$$B_{d_2}(x,r) \subseteq B_{d_1}(x,r)\tag{1}$$

(if $y \in B_{d_2}(x,r)$, we have $d_2(x,y) < r$ and then also $d_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) < r$ so $y \in B_{d_1}(x,r)$)

From $(1)$ it follows that $B_{d_2}(x,r) \subseteq O$, and as $x \in O$ was arbitrary, by definition $O$ is $d_2$-open.

No triangle inequality etc....

Comment: Because it seems that in terms of topology I'm mentally yet a juvenile, as I can't think in terms of easy abstractions, I have to ask that how did you know that the $B_{d_2}$ is contained in $B_{d_1}$ before writing this proof. I mean that 1.) have you already seen this kind of proof before, 2.) did you notice that that inclusion is necessary for the proof and therefore attacked it immediately or 3.) can one reason about the inclusion from the inequality assumption: "*Distances between points w.r.t $d_2$ are at least as much as with $d_1$*"?

Comment: @SickSeries the latter: we get $d_1$ below $r$ *because* we get $d_2$ below it (by being in a ball) and then $d_1$ is even smaller so *also* in such a ball. So $\le$ of metrics implies the *reverse* inclusion for the balls (of same centre and radius) and then you reason about what it means for the open sets: $d_1$ open means a ball inside so the smaller ball (for the larger metric) is also inside etc.